# i am getting Error: Not found: 'dart:html'

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i solve this error and please tell me why do we get this ,
the given below is my main.dart file

[image]

Comment: You cannot use `dart:html` unless your target platform is a web application. It looks lik you are trying to make a Flutter application and run it as an Android application on an Android phone.

Comment: @julemand101 Yes, I was trying to  make a mobile application and not web,

Comment: Ok, can you show us the content of `main.dart`? Also, please don't post screenshots unless it is the only way to communicate your problem. You should post your error and code as text.

Comment: @julemand101 I got your point and thanks for your advice and time

Comment: Where in your project have you inserted the line `import 'dart:html'`?

Comment: How do you get to know that i have inserted it into gradel ,please can you point it out...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240891/discussion-between-julemand101-and-manishyadav).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described on the front-page of the API documentation for Dart: https://api.dart.dev

> - dart:html: DOM manipulation for web apps (available only to web apps).
> - dart:io: I/O for non-web apps.

So `dart:html` can only be used if your target platform is web (so Dart code compiled to JavaScript). In your case, you are trying to make an Android application which runs native on your phone. You can therefore not use `dart:html` but should instead look into `dart:io` (which are not available for web-applications) if you need access to IO operations.

Comment: Thanks  I got it!!!

Comment: @Manishyadav I know, but I wanted to post an answer you can accept so other people can use if they find your problem.

Comment: is that fine???

Comment: Well, if you think my answer solves your problem described in the question segment, then it is fine to accept it. If you think it is missing some details, please inform me so I can fix the answer.

Comment: I let you know if I find missing details, You bookmark this question   if and only if you need

Answer (score 2):

I deleted import 'dart:html'; line. And its ok.
Also, don't forget to delete in other .dart file such as class or widgets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Deleting the `import 'dart:html'` line helped me. I'm not sure how it got there